# Modificar campos phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Acabo de empezar a trabajar con `BDs`, y estoy intentando actualizar el valor de un campo en todas las filas. Es decir en la tabla FRUTAS tengo la columna `color`, y quiero poner que todas las frutas tengas color `rojo`. El caso es que al intentar hacerlo en sql de esta manera, no me deja.

```
UPDATE frutas SET color = 'rojo'
```

Y me lanza este error:

```
UPDATE `frutas` SET `id_fruta`=[value-1],`color`=[value-2] WHERE 1
```

¿Alguien me podría decir cómo puedo realizar el cambio mediante una sentencia sql?

Comment: El `UPDATE` lo estas haciendo en la consola que trae PhpMyAdmin para las sentencias SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que veo estas usando la consola de `SQL` que trae **phpMyAdmin**.

Básicamente lo que pasa es que no estas usando la sintaxis correcta. 
Por eso si tu quieres que la columna `color` cambie todos sus campos a `Rojo` debes ejecutar la sentencia:

```
UPDATE `frutas` SET `Color`='Rojo';
```

En **phpMyAdmin** debes utilizar las comillas simples `' '` para los values de los campos como en este caso en de `color`.

Mientras que para los nombres de **tablas** o **columnas** se utiliza el acento grave `` . Quizás de primeras es un poco lioso, pero te acostumbras rápido.

Espero que te sea útil.

Comment: Mil gracias eso era lo que me estaba pasando, que estaba poniendo mal las comillas

Answer (score 3):

Te confirmo las setencias tanto en la consola de PHPMyAdmin y en la consola de MySQL como servicio por separado

```
UPDATE frutas SET color = 'rojo';
```

EXPLICACIÓN

Cuando usas la consola interactiva del phpmyadmin, te pone una estructura de ejemplo para que lleves acabo la consulta; eso último que muestras no es un error es el ejemplo que te provee dicha herramienta.

Lo que debes hacer es escribir tal cual tu consulta y posterior en la pestaña sql y en la esquina inferior derecha buscar el botón que dice CONTINUAR lo que te permitirá llevar a cabo tu modificación masiva; pero ojo tal cual te la estoy poniendo

ENTONCES PARA QUE ME PONE ESE EJEMPLO MI PHP MYADMIN??

Sencillo te esta indicando que va a hacer una modificación pero donde el id sea igual a 1, mira

```
UPDATE frutas SET color = 'rojo' WHERE id = 1;
```

> Esa es la única diferencia, si usas el where solo afectas una fila y
>   si no lo usas afectas a todos los registros de tu tabla

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

> Aunque estes trabajando en la consola de php myadmin puedes usar solo
>   para los valores que son cadenas de texto o fechas las comillas
>   simples '' no necesitas usar las invertidas